# JMH Micro Benchmarking with JMH for java static method returns OutOfBounds exception

Tags: java, list, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I set up this benchmark test

```
static Random rand = new Random();
static int  n = rand.nextInt(999) + 1;

@Setup
public static final void setup(){
int x = 1000;
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    id.add(rand.nextInt(500) + 1);
    property_address.add(rand.nextInt(1000) + 1);
    email.add(rand.nextInt(1000) + 1);
    owner_address.add(rand.nextInt(1000) + 1);
    price.add(rand.nextInt(1000) + 1);
    date_sold.add(rand.nextInt(1000) + 1);
  }
  System.out.println("Setup Complete");

} 

   @Benchmark
   public static void getPropertybyId(){
    System.out.println(id.get(n) +", "+ property_address.get(n) +", "+ 
    first_name.get(n) +", "+ last_name.get(n) +", "+
    email.get(n) +", "+
    owner_address.get(n) +", "+
    price.get(n)+", "+
    date_sold.get(n));

}
```

Because I want to see how fast getPropertyById works, I want to populate the Lists id/property/email with 1000 random integer elements and then get a random element from each array at the same index (n).

This is the actual method but I took out the scanner in order to use random data so the benchmarking doesn't have to wait for user input

```
public static void getPropertybyId(){
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
   System.out.println("Enter an id number to search properties: ");
   int n = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
  reader.close();
  System.out.println(id.get(n) +", "+ property_address.get(n) +", "+ first_name.get(n) +", "+ last_name.get(n) +", "+
  email.get(n) +", "+
  owner_address.get(n) +", "+
  price.get(n)+", "+
  date_sold.get(n));
}
```

I get the following error

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 902, Size: 0
       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
       at org.sample.MyBenchmark.getPropertybyId(MyBenchmark.java:80)
```

Comment: You're filling 6 different lists in your setup method, yet you're using 8 different lists in your benchmark methods. Naturally, 2 out of these 8 lists have zero elements, like your exception says (Size: 0)

Comment: :OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Comment: Would you be able to tell me why my benchmark warmup iteration runs indefinitely https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/photo/115135191238195349859/6560590680120720002?authkey=CPu96q-9lYDwRw

Comment: I have one suggestion: don't print in a JMH test. You'll be mainly benchmarking the IO performance of your console. Instead, use `return`: `return id.get(n) +", "+ property_address.get(n) +", "+ 
    first_name.get(n) +", "+ last_name.get(n) +", "+
    email.get(n) +", "+
    owner_address.get(n) +", "+
    price.get(n)+", "+
    date_sold.get(n);`

Comment: I just did it and it worked, thank you very much for your time you've helped me alot